# How to force the dependency to include an artifact with a specific version number

Tags: java, maven, gwt, maven-3

I get this error when trying to build GWT project with maven:

> Your project declares dependency on gwt-user 2.6.0. This plugin is
>   designed for at least gwt version 2.7.0

As I found out gwt-user 2.6.0 is downloaded with com.google.gwt.eventbinder.
How I can force com.google.gwt.eventbinder using gwt-user 2.7.0 instead 2.6.0?

The strange thing is that the build worked before I did 'git pull'.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.prognoz.ra.okhs</groupId>
<artifactId>gwtclient</artifactId>
<version>0.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <gwt.version>2.7.0</gwt.version>
    <maven.version>3.0.5</maven.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <version.org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.maven.plugin>2.7.0</version.org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.maven.plugin>
    <webappDirectory>war</webappDirectory>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>${maven.version}</maven>
</prerequisites>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.moxieapps.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>highcharts</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/highcharts-1.7.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.prognoz.ra.dbutil</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbutil</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/out/artifacts/dbutil_jar/dbutil.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.org.apache.commons.fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.liferay.org.apache.commons.fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt.eventbinder</groupId>
        <artifactId>eventbinder</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.maven.plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <compileReport>true</compileReport>
              <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
              <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>Tomcat8_local</server>
                <path>/ra-okhs</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>m2e</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>m2e.version</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

The problem is eventbinder has dependency on gwt-user artifact. it uses 2.6.0 by default you can see it by using this command.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

[image]

If you add this dependency block to your pom;

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
   <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

It will look like this...

This means your project will have gwt-user 2.7.0 all the time, i haven't tested if everything is ok with version compatibility or something your problem will be solved..

**Solution 2**
Thanks for the @Thomas Broyer's comment we can force eventbinder to use 2.7.0 gwt-user or any gwt dependency. if we just add this dependency management to our pom

```
<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: Or you could use dependencyManagement. Starting with 2.7.0 you can use scope=import with com.google.gwt:gwt to import gwt-user, gwt-servlet, gwt-dev, etc. in dependencyManagement.

Comment: Solution 2 was really helpful to fix the conflict between reflections>0.9.11 and Guava<18.0