# How to exclude the library from Maven if I do not see it in the dependency tree?

Tags: java, maven, jar, osgi

I am getting this error: `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory` when using a jar library in my project. My project is a Maven, but the library itself probably not. I have installed it into the local Maven repository and included it as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.misclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>misclient</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version> 
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

My Maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] com.softgile:asan:atlassian-plugin:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.jira:jira-api:jar:8.12.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.annotations:atlassian-annotations:jar:2.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.ofbiz:entityengine-share:jar:1.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.ofbiz:entityengine:jar:1.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- jta:jta:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.collectors:atlassian-collectors-util:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- opensymphony:webwork:jar:1.4-atlassian-30:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.html:atlassian-html-encoder:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- webwork:pell-multipart-request:jar:1.31.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.core:atlassian-core:jar:7.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-atlassian-2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.image:atlassian-image-consumer:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.core:atlassian-core-user:jar:7.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.core:atlassian-core-thumbnail:jar:7.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-jpeg:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-core:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-metadata:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.common:common-lang:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.common:common-io:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.twelvemonkeys.common:common-image:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-tiff:jar:3.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras:jar:3.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.velocity:atlassian-velocity:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- opensymphony:oscore:jar:2.2.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- osworkflow:osworkflow:jar:2.9.0-atlassian-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- opensymphony:propertyset:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.cache:atlassian-cache-api:jar:4.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.instrumentation:atlassian-instrumentation-core:jar:3.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- io.atlassian.util.concurrent:atlassian-util-concurrent:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.beehive:beehive-api:jar:4.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.tenancy:atlassian-tenancy-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.event:atlassian-event:jar:4.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.upgrade:upgrade-task-framework-api:jar:2.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.crowd:embedded-crowd-api:jar:4.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:26.0-jre:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.5.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.fugue:fugue:jar:2.7.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- io.atlassian.fugue:fugue:jar:4.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13-atlassian-4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13-atlassian-4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.mail:atlassian-mail:jar:5.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.threadlocal:atlassian-threadlocal:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-api:jar:8.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-unshaded:jar:v20181008:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-externs:jar:v20181008:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.26:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:jar:1.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.velocity.htmlsafe:velocity-htmlsafe:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-api:jar:5.3.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webfragment:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webfragment-api:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.ozymandias:atlassian-plugin-point-safety:jar:1.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.13:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource:jar:4.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource-spi:jar:4.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource-api:jar:4.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:4.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.sourcemap:sourcemap:jar:1.7.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource-compiler-gcc:jar:4.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.gadgets:atlassian-gadgets-api:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.johnson:atlassian-johnson-core:jar:4.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-servlet:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1-atlassian-2:provided
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17-atlassian-2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.profiling:atlassian-profiling:jar:3.2.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.scheduler:atlassian-scheduler-api:jar:3.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.analytics:analytics-api:jar:6.1.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.application:atlassian-application-api:jar:2.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.atlassian:lucene-extras:jar:7.3.1-atlassian-4:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.plugin:atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation:jar:1.2.13:provided
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner:jar:2.0.1:test
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2-atlassian-1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.plugins.rest:atlassian-rest-common:jar:1.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.plugins.rest:com.atlassian.jersey-library:pom:1.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-asl:jar:0.9.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- net.sourceforge.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.2:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.sal:sal-api:jar:3.0.7:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.wink:wink-client:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wink:wink-common:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxrs_1.1_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.templaterenderer:atlassian-template-renderer-api:jar:2.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.misclient:misclient:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.aui:auiplugin:jar:8.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.upm:licensing-api:jar:2.21.4:provided
[INFO] \- com.atlassian.upm:upm-api:jar:2.21:provided
```

The library that I am using and which gives and error is `org.misclient:misclient:jar:1.0:compile`.

```
2021-02-01 18:59:05,017+0100 http-nio-8080-exec-12 ERROR seyid.a 1139x8875x1 7rxlsq 5.197.138.80,127.0.0.1 /rest/asanrest/1.0/message/getAdocInfo [c.a.p.r.c.error.jersey.ThrowableExceptionMapper] Uncaught exception thrown by REST service: Exception from underlying library
ee.cyber.asanimza.toolkit.MisServiceException: Exception from underlying library
        at ee.cyber.asanimza.toolkit.SignedContainer.loadFromBytesArray(SignedContainer.java:202)
        at com.softgile.misclient.MisServiceMethods.getInfoFromContainer(MisServiceMethods.java:229)
        at com.softgile.rest.AsanRest.getAdocInfo(AsanRest.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        ... 1 filtered
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        ... 19 filtered
        at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter$JerseyOsgiServletContainer.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:160)
        ... 1 filtered
        at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:70)
        ... 32 filtered
        at com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.web.ExternalCustomerLockoutFilter.doFilter(ExternalCustomerLockoutFilter.java:55)
        ... 8 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.mobile.web.filter.MobileAppRequestFilter.doFilter(MobileAppRequestFilter.java:59)
        ... 4 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.mobile.login.MobileLoginSuccessFilter.doFilter(MobileLoginSuccessFilter.java:54)
        ... 3 filtered
        at com.atlassian.diagnostics.internal.platform.monitor.http.HttpRequestMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HttpRequestMonitoringFilter.java:55)
        ... 8 filtered
        at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21)
        ... 43 filtered
        at com.atlassian.ratelimiting.internal.filter.RateLimitFilter.doFilter(RateLimitFilter.java:73)
        ... 17 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(JiraSecurityFilter.java:66)
        ... 1 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.doFilter(JiraSecurityFilter.java:64)
        ... 16 filtered
        at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:38)
        ... 19 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.doFilter(CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.java:30)
        ... 5 filtered
        at com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.web.CustomerContextSettingFilter.lambda$invokeFilterChain$0(CustomerContextSettingFilter.java:215)
        at com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.api.util.context.ReentrantThreadLocalBasedCodeContext.rteInvoke(ReentrantThreadLocalBasedCodeContext.java:136)
        at com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.api.util.context.ReentrantThreadLocalBasedCodeContext.runOutOfContext(ReentrantThreadLocalBasedCodeContext.java:89)
        at com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.utils.context.CustomerContextServiceImpl.runOutOfCustomerContext(CustomerContextServiceImpl.java:47)
        at com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.web.CustomerContextSettingFilter.outOfCustomerContext(CustomerContextSettingFilter.java:206)
        at com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.web.CustomerContextSettingFilter.doFilterImpl(CustomerContextSettingFilter.java:134)
        at com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.web.CustomerContextSettingFilter.doFilter(CustomerContextSettingFilter.java:123)
        ... 4 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jwt.internal.servlet.JwtAuthFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthFilter.java:37)
        ... 8 filtered
        at com.atlassian.ratelimiting.internal.filter.RateLimitPreAuthFilter.doFilter(RateLimitPreAuthFilter.java:71)
        ... 3 filtered
        at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21)
        ... 4 filtered
        at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.LocationCleanerFilter.doFilter(LocationCleanerFilter.java:36)
        ... 7 filtered
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
        at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:88)
        at net.bull.javamelody.JiraMonitoringFilter.doFilter(JiraMonitoringFilter.java:137)
        ... 22 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.MetricsCollectorFilter.doFilter(MetricsCollectorFilter.java:25)
        ... 25 filtered
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at ee.sk.digidoc.factory.SAXDigiDocFactory.readSignedDocOfType(SAXDigiDocFactory.java:342)
        at ee.sk.digidoc.factory.SAXDigiDocFactory.readSignedDocOfType(SAXDigiDocFactory.java:489)
        at ee.cyber.asanimza.toolkit.SignedContainer.loadFromBytesArray(SignedContainer.java:197)
        ... 287 more
```

I have added 2 exclusions to get rid of xerces:xercesImpl and xml-apis:xml-apis,

```
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

but still get the same error. Is there anything else related to SAXParserFactory?

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the library?

Comment: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserFactoryImpl.html
This class actually implements javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory, so your error is due to OSGi rules, it seems. This question seems very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638091/classcastexception-org-apache-xerces-jaxp-documentbuilderfactoryimpl-cannot-be

Comment: Yes, it is very similar, but how should I solve it now? Which packages should I import and what to exclude?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not exclude the SAXParser and try to include it for your lib (as you use provided lib `xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:provided`). If you have an access to it's code you could just include (assemble with) SAXParser classes into the misclient jar or maybe change the version of xerces. Also you could maybe assemble all of the libs together misclient + xerces + yourone.

[How to force the dependency to include an artifact with a specific version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528157/how-to-force-the-dependency-to-include-an-artifact-with-a-specific-version-numbe)

```
    <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Perhaps you could include needed lib by this

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not have access to modify the code of misclient jar. I have tried to use the solution to force the dependency to include an artifact with specific version number:

    `<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>`
Did not work either, same error

Comment: But why do you use the same version of xerces as provided (by Application Server) one?
As I understand it doesn't work with misclient? 
I would try to find xerces version with javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory class/package

Comment: Yes, I just don't know the version that I will need to use. How can I know the version for misclient? I cannot find any version information inside that jar file.